# Javascript выполнение функции увеличивающиеся по клику количество раз

Tags: javascript, функции

При нажатии на кнопку у меня действие с первого раза не отрабатывает, а со второго раза отрабатывает 2 раза, потом при нажатии еще раз, отрабатывает 3 раза и так далее с арифметической прогрессией. Функцией displayRooms - выводит комнаты, displayRoom - ее отображает, а setRoom - выполняется при нажатии на кнопки

```
function displayRooms() {
  rooms.orderByValue().once("value", function(snapshot) {
    snapshot.forEach(function(data) {
      console.log("The roomname is ->" + data.key());
        $(".rooms").prepend('<li><button type="button" class= "rooms1" id="' + 
        data.key() + '" onclick="setRoomName()"' + 
        '>' + data.key() + '</button></li>');
    });
  });

function setRoomName() {
  $(".rooms1").click(function() {
    roomName = this.id;
    console.log(this.id);
    displayRoom();
  })
};

function displayRoom() {
  roomRef = rooms.child("/" + roomName);
  roomRef.once("value", function(snapshot) {
    var data = snapshot.val();
    console.log(data);
    var arr = $.map(data, function(el) { return el });
    console.log(arr);
    var countMsg = arr.length;
    console.log(countMsg);
    $(".main").empty();
    for (var i = 0; i<countMsg; i++) {
      var arr1 = $.map(arr[i], function(el) { return el });
      console.log("this is a username ->" + arr1[0] + " & this is a message->" + arr1[1]);
      $(".main").prepend('<p>' + arr1[0] + ' says: ' + arr1[1] + '</p>');
    }
  });
};
```

Вопрос состоит в следующем, как сделать так чтобы функция не повторялась?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Каждый раз, когда вызывается функция `setRoomName`, она добавляет новый `click` обработчик всем элементам `".rooms1"`.

Уберите `onclick="setRoomName()"`, назначайте обработчик события `click` один раз, используя делегирование:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $(document).on("click", ".rooms1", function() {
    console.log(this.id);
    displayRoom(this.id);
  });
};

function displayRoom(roomName){
  ...
}
```